# get facebook user friends birthday

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a way to get facebook user friends birthday using iOS Facebook SDK? Also, I've tried to load user friends birthday from user events but I've only got the events, not birthdays.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let facebookReadPermissions = ["user_events"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
            return
        }

        FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(self.facebookReadPermissions, handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                println(error)
            } else if result.isCancelled {
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                println("cancelled")
            } else {
                var allPermsGranted = true

                let perms = result.grantedPermissions as NSSet
                let grantedPermissions = Array(result.grantedPermissions).map( {"\($0)"} )
                for permission in self.facebookReadPermissions {
                    if !contains(grantedPermissions, permission) {
                        allPermsGranted = false
                        break
                    }
                }
                if allPermsGranted {
                    // Do work
                    println("all perm granted, success!")

                    let fbToken = result.token.tokenString
                    let fbUserID = result.token.userID
                    println(fbToken)
                    println(fbUserID)

                    self.getUserEvents()
                } else {
                    println("failure")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func getUserEvents() {
        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "events"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    println(result)
                    println("----------------------")
                    println(result as! NSDictionary)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    events =     {
        data =         (
                        {
                description = dfgfdgfdg;
                id = 791086224356028;
                name = "B party";
                "rsvp_status" = attending;
                "start_time" = "2015-08-30";
            },
                        {
                description = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442";
                id = 1624498701141585;
                name = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442";
                place =                 {
                    id = 356733231072690;
                    location =                     {
                        city = Kirovohrad;
                        country = Ukraine;
                        latitude = "48.5046610418";
                        longitude = "32.2676611219";
                        zip = 250;
                    };
                    name = "\U0433. \U041a\U0438\U0440\U043e\U0432\U043e\U0433\U0440\U0430\U0434 , \U0423\U043a\U0440\U0430\U0438\U043d\U0430";
                };
                "rsvp_status" = attending;
                "start_time" = "2015-08-30";
            }
        );
        paging =         {
            cursors =             {
                after = TVRZAeU5EUTVPRGN3TVRFME1UVTROVG94TkRRd09URTRNREF3T2pFMk5UQTRORGc1TmpnME9EVTRNUT09;
                before = TnpreE1EZAzJNakkwTXpVMk1ESTRPakUwTkRBNU1UZA3dNREE2TVRjMk9UQTRNVE0xTmpnM09UWXgZD;
            };
        };
    };
    id = 1569554686600399;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From Facebook api v2.0 onwards, all friend permissions have been removed. You cannot get a friend's birthday. Reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog